# Is polynomial approximation a linear operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, approximation

Lets call the "operation" of approximating any function $f(x)$ in a given intervall by a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ such that the least squares error is minimized $\varphi: f(x) \rightarrow p(x)$.
Are the following statements valid?:
$$\varphi (f(x)+g(x)) = \varphi (f(x)) + \varphi(g(x))$$
$$\varphi (a\cdot f(x)) = a\cdot \varphi (f(x))$$

If not, is it valid in some special cases?

I'm aware of my poor notation, but I hope you still understand my question

Comment: There is no such thing as a polynomial that minimizes the error (unless you somehow restrict the acceptable polynomials).

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention: the degree of the polynomial is fixed. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to make your claim precise.

Let $V$ be the set of (say) continuous real functions on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Then $V$ is a real vector space and 
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b \! f(x)g(x)dx
$$
defines an inner product on $V$.
With respect to this inner product, your map $L:f \mapsto p$ is the orthogonal projection $V \to P_n$, where $P_n$ is the subspace of polynomials of degree at most $n$. Therefore, $L$ is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [least-squares approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem) of a function by a polynomial of given degree is linear. In the discrete case, this follows trivially from the explicit expression for the polynomial coefficients:
$$\beta=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T y$$